# add options to .vue file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

In vue docs you see something like this:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello'
  },
  template: `<div>
        {{ message }}
    </div>`,
  methods: {
    reverseMessage: function () {
      return this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  },
  computed: {
    // a computed getter
    reversedMessage: function () {
      // `this` points to the vm instance
      return this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
})
```

however I am using the .vue files which has a different structure:

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ message }}
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class PlayerBid extends Vue {
    data() {
        return { message: 'Hello' };
    }
}
```

but I have no idea how to add all other (great) options in vue- computed/methods and other stuff.

clearly, I am missing something super easy here ...

Comment: You're using the class style so I would look at [this](https://class-component.vuejs.org/) and then [this](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) for the decorators.

Comment: @StevenB. awesome, seems like what I was looking for, checking this out

Answer (score 0):

I use the following way structure for my TS component

```js
export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'PlayerBid'
    data() {
        return { message: 'Hello' };
    },
    computed: {},
    methods: {}
})
```

When I have something to have structure it for referece

```js
import Vue, { VueConstructor } from 'vue'


interface IPlayerBid extends Vue {
  $refs: { foo: Vue }
}

export default (Vue as VueConstructor<IPlayerBid>).extend({
  name: 'PlayerBid',
  data() { return {} }
})
```

Comment: how is it related to my question ?

Answer (score 0):

following the advice of Steven B, here's how I resolved it:

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ message }}
        {{ myComputed }}
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class PlayerBid extends Vue {
    data() {
        return { message: 'Hello' };
    }

    get myComputed() { return this.$data.message + ' computed !'; }

    method1() { /* do something useful here */ }
/* 
this is the same as 
    computed: {
        myComputed: () => { return data.message + ' computed !'; }
    },
    methods: {
       method1: () =>  { /* do something useful here */ }
    }
*/ 

}
```